# Installing RabbitVCS on Ubuntu Jammy 22.04

Tags: 22.04, ppa, rabbitvcs

I am trying to install RabbitVCS on Ubuntu 22.04 using PPA but I am getting this error:

```
Err:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release

  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]

Reading package lists... Done

E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Upon investigation, it appears that the PPA does not exist in [https://launchpad.net/~rabbitvcs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Erabbitvcs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Is there a way to solve this? Or are there alternatives to RabbitVCS?

Comment: It appears to be [available from Ubuntu's own "universe" repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/rabbitvcs-core)

Comment: How would I install that repository? I am following the wiki and installing it through PPA at the moment using:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa`

How would installing from the universe repository work?

Comment: [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not available then you just have to remove your ubuntu version and roll back to a supported one. which looking at your link is utopic 14.04

Comment: Thanks I will try that